# Зайчик-побегайчик

Tags: цельное-выражение

Откуда пошло это название и существует ли похожее *"зайчик-по**пры**гайчик"* или это просто неудачная переделка? Неудачная в плане искажения существующего, а так, на мой взгляд, лучше второе при отсутствии первого — зайцы всё-таки скорее прыгают, чем бегают.

Comment: В сказках больше получается, что зайцы бегают. Из Теремка: *Бежит мимо зайчик-побегайчик.* А прыгают точно кузнечики и т.п., кто бегать даже гипотетически не может.

Comment: https://www.papmambook.ru/articles/220/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пошло это от "заяц-побегаец" (персонаж сказки "Теремок") - заяц пробегал мимо. Позже возникли вариации с суффиксом. Вариант "попрыгайчик" выглядит ненужным подражанием (в угоду рифме) классическому окказионализму - на фоне словарного слова "попрыгун(чик)". Оригинал же можно оправдать отсутствием слова "побегун" в прямом значении (синоним - "отлынщик"); в сказке создан единообразный ряд: лягушка-квакушка, мышка-норушка и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Насчёт отлынщика не очень понял только.

Comment: В словарях синонимов приводится такое значение слова "побегун".

Comment: Исправлю название. Оригинальный текст сказки "**Теремок**": (побега**ец**): http://education.simcat.ru/dou170/img/1504704292_oom_po_teatralizovannoy_deyatelnosti_po_skazke_teremok.docx

Comment: А вроде действительно, как говорит oleed, в "Теремке" за**йчик**-побега**йчик** только, а не заяц-побегаец (только что проверил). Или у него есть разные версии?

Comment: Думаю, что это более современные версии, ранние были без "сюсюкания" (в старину и жизнь была суровее), мне в своё время именно так читали ("побегаец" запомнилось).

Comment: Понятно, интересно!